# How is the process closed?

Tags: kubuntu

[image]

How can I close the unauthorized process on Ctrl+D together because did not work. Is there another button or a way to close it ????

Comment: Ctrl + C................

Comment: Also, to achieve what is required!!!

Comment: Can you clarify

Comment: I tried all the buttons to finish the process, but to no avail

Comment: try `ctrl + z` and what do you mean by unauthorized didn't you type that command in ?

Comment: I did not work either. I mean how do I close the process so I can write a new command?!

Comment: You can't write a new command until the process is closed. Press `ctrl + c` or `ctrl +z` to close the process.